# How to link JDBC driver to EJB project missing WEB-INF folder

Tags: java, eclipse, jdbc, ejb

I have Enterprise Appilcation Solution in Neon Eclipse, which envelope EJB and Servlet projects and deployed to Wildfly 10 server.
Servlet calls EJB for access DB.
If I put JDBC driver in WEB-INF folder of Servlet project, all is going well, but if I move the code to EJB and link the driver as external JAR (see screenshot), I get error:

```
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver from [Module "deployment.NeoflexBank.ear.Neoflex.jar:main" from Service Module Loader]
```

Here is the code I use for access the DB:

```
    public String test() {
        String output = "";

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/neoflex";
        String username="root";
        String password="";
        String query="select * from clients";
        Connection conn;
        try {
            conn = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
            Statement stmt = (Statement) conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

            while(rs.next())
            {
                output += rs.getInt("id");
                output += rs.getString("username");
                output += rs.getString("birth_date");
                output += rs.getString("name");
                output += rs.getString("surename");
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            return e.toString();
        }

        return output;
    }
```

[image: Troubles on JDBC linking]

Comment: Yes, because I move the code to EJB project, and it doesn't see the WEB-INF of servlet project. But I solvet it. I put the driver in EarContent of Enterprise Application Project (NeoflexBank).

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question, but we have had an application being marked as in HIGH risk of SQL Injection (!?) by the security team because of some hard coded built SQL statement (INSERT and UPDATE). Think about moving everything to prepared statement or callable statement. It is also better from a performance point of view by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to do this in a Java EE server is to define a DataSource and then use that for getting JDBC connections:

1. move the mysql-connector-java-5.1.40-bin.jar into the `standalone\deployments` directory of your WildFly installation.
2. start up your WildFly server and open the admin console at http://localhost:9990. You may have to follow some instructions to set up a bit of security here.
3. click on the `Configuration` tab, and then click on:

   a. Subsystems

   b. Datasources

   c. Non-XA
4. Click the blue `Add` button and follow the prompts.

Now, the code in your EJB will look a bit like:

```
@Stateless
public class SomeEJB {

   @Resource(name="java:/MySqlDS")
   private DataSource ds;

   public String test() {
        String output = "";

        String query="select * from clients";

        try {
            try (Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
                 Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
                 ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query)) {

                while(rs.next())
                {
                    output += rs.getInt("id");
                    output += rs.getString("username");
                    output += rs.getString("birth_date");
                    output += rs.getString("name");
                    output += rs.getString("surename");
                }
            } 
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            return e.toString();
        }

        return output;
    }
}
```

This decouples your application from the database configuration. The DataSource configuration can also be done from a command line script.